# OpenCL memory consistency

Tags: memory, opencl

I have a question concerning the OpenCL memory consistency model. Consider the following kernel:

```
__kernel foo() {
    __local lmem[1];
    lmem[0]  = 1;
    lmem[0] += 2;
}
```

In this case, is any synchronization or memory fence necessary to ensure that `lmem[0] == 3`?

According to section 3.3.1 of the OpenCL specification,

> within a work-item memory has load / store consistency.

To me, this says that the assignment will always be executed before the increment.

However, section 6.12.9 defines the `mem_fence` function as follows:

> Orders loads and stores of a work-item executing a kernel. This means that loads and stores preceding the mem_fence will be committed to memory before any loads and stores following the mem_fence.

Doesn't this contradict section 3.3.1? Or maybe my understanding of load / store consistency is wrong? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as only one work-item performs read/write access to a `local` memory cell, that work-item has a consistent view of it. Committing to memory using a barrier is only necessary to propagate writes to other work-items in the work-group. For example, an OpenCL implementation would be permitted to keep any changes to `local` memory in private registers until a barrier is encountered. Within the work-item, everything would appear fine, but other work-items would never see these changes. This is how the phrase "**committed to memory**" should be interpreted in 6.12.9.

Essentially, the interaction between local memory and barriers boils down to this:

Between barriers:

1. Only one work-item is allowed read/write access to a local memory cell.
   ***OR***
2. Any number of work-items in a work-group is allowed read-only access to a local memory cell.

In other words, no work-item may read or write to a local memory cell which is written to by another work-item after the last barrier.